# Have processing icons appear during custom button action

Tags: acumatica

I have a process which is activated by a button on a screen - but I'd like to know how to make it work like a process button, where the spinning wheel happens and the green checkbox appears at the end.  I've got the following code, which I had wrapped in a PXLongOperation.StartOperation(...) as follows (the PXLongOperation is commented out here, because it didn't seem to be doing anything):

```
 public PXAction<APInvoice> CreatePOBillings;
   // [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXProcessButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create PO Billings", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    protected void createPOBillings()
    {
        int i = 0;
        try
        {
            //This wraps the whole process into a 'PXLongOperation' function that will create the spinning 'busy' wheel at the top toolbar...
            //PXLongOperation.StartOperation(this, delegate()
            //{

                var apinvoice = (APInvoice)Base.Document.Current;
                if (apinvoice == null) return;

                string RefNbr = apinvoice.RefNbr;

                //Run the stored procedure which will get the records to create the Project Transactions.  This will populate the table 'xCreatePOBilings':
                var pars = new PXSPParameter[] { new PXSPInParameter("@p_RefNbr", RefNbr) }; //, new PXSPOutParameter("p2", outp2) };
                var results = PXDatabase.Execute("xspMarketingPOBilling", pars);

                //Get the dataset from the xCreatePOBillings table which was populated from the stored procedure above:
                PXResultset<xCreatePOBillings> res = PXSelect<xCreatePOBillings,
                                                     Where<xCreatePOBillings.ponbr, Equal<Required<xCreatePOBillings.ponbr>>>
                                                    ,OrderBy<Asc<xCreatePOBillings.ponbr
                                                            ,Asc<xCreatePOBillings.destProject
                                                            ,Asc<xCreatePOBillings.startDate>>>>>.Select(Base, RefNbr);

                //Create the graph for the Project Transactions screen:
                RegisterEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<RegisterEntry>();

                //Create a new cache object for the header of Project Transactions:
                PMRegister pmreg = new PMRegister();
                pmreg.Module = "PM";
                graph.Document.Insert(pmreg);

                //Define the cache for the Project Transactions screen's grid records:
                PMTran pmtrn;

                foreach (PXResult<xCreatePOBillings> rec in res)
                {
                   ....

                   graph.Actions.PressSave();
             //});
```

What is the best way to achieve this, if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the static `PXLongOperation.StartOperation` method is invoked inside a BLC extension class, as first parameter it can only accept `Base` property instead of `this` keyword:

```
PXLongOperation.StartOperation(Base, delegate()
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks again, Ruslan!

Comment: Always a pleasure to help, Peter!